# How to keep some static data for future use in a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

When the app starts, I got some static data (array) from the server, and I need to use this data for a spinner, on different activities. So this data should be available from different activities at different times to create a spinner.

How can I make this? How can I generate a spinner in code (spinner data is key = value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of data contains that array? Maybe you can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save it.

You can read about generating spinner [here.](http://adanware.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html) `CountryAdapter` class is example of making spinner adapter which displays items in spinner drop down list.

EDIT:
Put your data into Hashtable and create 2 methods to save and read your data from SharedPreferences:

```
public boolean saveData( Hashtable<String, String> myData) {

    Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    for (String key : myData.values()) {
        editor.putString(key, myData.get(key));
    }
    return editor.commit();
}

public Hashtable<String, String>  restoreData() {
    Hashtable<String, String> myData = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("size", 0);

    for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
        myData.put(sharedPreferences.getString("key"+i, "key+1"), sharedPreferences.getString("value"+i, "value+1"));
    }

    return myData;
}
```

Comment: its a string array, json key = value. and then I need to have sponner or something like dropdown selectbox. so that I can seelct some value and then from code get key for this value.